# How do I display todos that are associated with a TodoList on Theymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am making a todo app in which there are TodoLists on the index page and when you click the TodoList, you can see all of the todos that are associated with it.

e.g. When you click the TodoList "Shopping" on the index page, you can see a show page which has "todos" like clothes, food etc.

TodoListController.java

```
package com.teamlab.todolist.web;

import com.teamlab.todolist.domain.TodoList;
import com.teamlab.todolist.repository.TodoListRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/todoLists")
public class TodoListController {

    @Autowired
    TodoListRepository todoListRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public String getAllTodoLists(Model model) {
        List<TodoList> todoLists = todoListRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("todoLists", todoLists);
        return "todoLists/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public String showAllTodos(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        TodoList todoList = todoListRepository.findOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("todoList", todoList);
        return "todoLists/show";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createTodoList(@ModelAttribute TodoList todoList) {
        todoListRepository.save(todoList);
        return "redirect:/todoLists";
    }

}
```

I don`t have any code written in my show.html page.

I previously worked on a Rails app where I had a course object and within that course object were lesson objects. I was able to display all the lessons associated with a single course by just pulling the associated views out in the view template as shown below.

```
<% @course.lessons.each do |lesson| %>
      <h2><%= link_to lesson.title, lesson_path(lesson.id) %></h2>
  <% end %>
```

I am not sure how to do it in Spring Boot and I`m also not sure whether this is the right approach to solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same in thymeleaf using `th:each`. You are returning all the todoList using `model.addAttribute("todoLists", todoLists);`. You can process the data in `todoLists` in UI using

```
<table >
    <tr th:each="todoList: ${todoLists}">
    <td th:text="${todoList.name}"></td>
    <td th:text="${todoList.priority}"></td>
    <td th:text="${todoList.status}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```